# Removing Unwanted Wine icon from Launcher

Tags: wine, launcher, shortcuts

I recently tried to install the `Logitech Gaming Software` (version `9.02.65`) in my `Ubuntu 18.04` environment. Since Logitech only provides this program for Windows and Mac, I wanted to install it on `Ubuntu` using `Wine 4.0`. However this didn't work out so well (in fact the GUI was completely unusable) so I decided to remove the Logitech Software and put it inside a Windows Virtual Machine.

I am now however left with an unwanted (and unusable) Logitech Gaming Software Link in my Ubuntu Launcher. The Link is not situated in `/usr/share/applications` nor is it in `~/.local/share/applications`.

**My question**: Where could the Logitech Gaming shortcut be situated and more importantly, how can I remove it from the launcher?

Comment: Sometimes wine drops a folder `/usr/share/applications/wine` with a lot of .desktop entries in it.  You could check that, if you haven't already. (I know you checked the /applications folder, but just making sure you looked in /wine)

Comment: Thanks for the tip but it‘s not there either :/

Comment: last try: /wine folder in ~/.local/share/applications/

Comment: Not all heroes wear capes :D It was indeed located in ~/.local/share/applications/wine - thank you

Comment: I'll post it as an answer, if you like, you can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes wine drops a folder in `/usr/share/applications/wine` and/or  `~/.local/share/applications/` with a lot of .desktop entries in it. You could check those, if you haven't already.