# When uninstalling wine application their icons stay, how to remove them?

Tags: software-installation, wine, uninstall, games

[image]

I want to remove "morrowind" and "manual". How do I do that?

Comment: See if this helps https://askubuntu.com/a/1122598/243321

Answer (score 1):

I went to ~/.local/share/applications  and deleted .desktop files. That did the job.

Comment: You're welcome.