# How can I remove the Epic Games Launcher Icon from the Application Menu?

Tags: uninstall, delete, cleanup, lutris

I recently installed Lutris --> Fortnite --> Epic Games --> and selected create shortcut to Applications Menu as opposed to Desktop for the Epic Games Launcher, Fornite worked briefly but the anti-cheat system would kick me out mid-game. Thus remove Fortnite via Lutris and Epic Games as a whole. But the Epic Games Launcher has since remained.

[image: epic_games_launcher]

When you try run the file, you get the following error

[image]

I have ran the following command to see if there are any files named Epic Games Launcher with the intention of running `gedit` to see if it has been modified to appear on the application menu

```
for app in /usr/share/applications/*.desktop; do echo "${app:24:-8}"; done
```

Navigating via `sudo nautilus` to find the file named Epic results in:
/usr/share/applications

[image]

And then filter on Ep*
[image]

But I get nothing, can someone please help, this will also help me understand more about how these applications are handled.

Comment: Check in  `~/.local/share/applications/wine`, if not in `wine` check in the `applications` folder.  See https://askubuntu.com/q/1122550/243321

Answer (score 2):

The Desktop Entry file you are looking is most probably in your local directory: `~/.local/share/applications/`. You can easily find file containing name of your app using recursive grep:

```
grep "Epic Games Launcher" ~/.local/share/applications/ -r
```

Comment: `rm  ~/.local/share/applications/wine*` makes the day

Answer (score 0):

Here are some steps to "Possibly" fix your issue

Go into terminal and type "su" and enter your root password
Now you are root! Now type sudo nautilus
Then go to the directory /usr/share applications
Now, instead of doing the command you did just click the search bar and search "Epic" and you should find epic games! Delete the desktop file then restart Gnome Shell by either killing the process in system monitor or by restarting the PC!

[image: Helpful image]
I hope this has helped your issue! If it hasn't feel free to comment and I will get to you quickly!

Comment: First: I needed to set a root password: `sudo passwd root`
Second: `sudo nautilus`
Third: navigate to directory /usr/share/applications

I cannot find any file named Epic or Launcher

Comment: How did you install the Epic Games launcher?

Answer (score 0):

EPIC_GAMES_LAUNCHER icon removed via the following method:

[image]

In the applications menu I search for the Epic Games Launcher to isolate it.
This brought up the path location of the icon for which I couldn't find before via the terminal using `which`/`find`/ `& mlocate`.

Step 1: Navigate to the path provided: `cd ~/.local/share/applications/wine/Programs/`

[image]

**This is the file I was looking for.**
[image]

Step 2: remove the file: `rm 'Epic Games Launcher.desktop'`

Step 3: restart the OS

Step 4: verify that the icon is gone [**DONE**]