# How to remove "Kindle" Icon from All Application

Tags: wine, icons, uninstall, winetricks

I am running Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS, Gnome Desktop. I installed Kindle for PC using the command `winetricks kindle`

It installed Kindle, and I was able to run the app correctly. I then wanted to uninstall it, and winetricks also added an icon saying **Uninstall Kindle** in Apps. I used it to uninstall it.

The problem now is that the **Kindle** and **Uninstall Kindle** Icons still exist in the Applications. Clicking on them says *Failed to Launch Kindle. Failed to change to Directory /path/to/kindle.exe (No such file or directory)* and a similar response to Uninstall Kindle which shows that it is uninstalled.

I have looked into both `/usr/share/applications/` and `~/.local/share/applications/` and there's nothing remotely related to Kindle or Amazon or Uninstall in there.

So, how do I remove these icons?

Comment: Per https://askubuntu.com/questions/1122550/removing-unwanted-wine-icon-from-launcher/1122598#1122598 check for a /wine folder in those directories you mention.

Answer (score 0):

Just search for "kindle" in your file manager and there should be a `.desktop` file or a folder related to Kindle there. Just delete them.